# Why is the minimum reputation to place a bounty so high?

Tags: discussion

I once stumbled upon a question, and I wanted to be a bit charitable. So I opened up the bounty menu, and it says that the minimum is 50 points. I don't want to give so much of my reputation; I only want to give 15 or 25 points, something that attracts people to the question but doesn't require a lot of sacrifice. Why can't the minimum be something lower for those who don't have as much rep?

Comment: You'll will find soon enough that 50 rep is virtually negligible :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An upvote is +10 reputation. An accept tick is +15 reputation. Both of them together is +25 reputation.

Making bounties that "cheap" would essentially make them extra upvotes/accepts. That's not what bounties are for. Bounties are to reward *exceptional* content and draw attention to a question that needs *additional* attention - resulting in users going out of their way to answer a question that would, otherwise, be left to rot.

Comment: Can you define "exceptional?" What kind of things does the question have to meet in order to deserve a bounty? There are plenty of questions out there that rot, [especially](http://superuser.com/unanswered) on other sites.

Comment: @oldmud0 A bounty is completely at the discretion of whoever wants to give it. But generally, bounties are intended to reward an answer that was much needed - either because it includes lots and lots of detail, or because the question didn't get a sufficient answer at all until that point.

Answer (score 8):

Giving lower amounts of reputation would devalue the purpose of a bounty - bounties push the question the bounty is placed on in to it's own tab which dramatically reduces the number of questions it has to compete against and increases its visibility.